# Can "conversant" be a noun?

Tags: nouns, is-it-a-word

Googling amongst the world's online dictionaries produces conflicting results, but on the whole indicates that the answer is "no". However, it feels so natural to say:

> The conversants conversed.

Whereas: "the conversationalists conversed" is a bit long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is uncommon but yes, conversant, can be a noun and means 'one party in a conversation', e.g, Her conversants never failed to remark on her bell-like laughter.

OED says: "B. sb. 1. A person who `converses' or is intimate with another; a familiar acquaintance. Obs."

Credit to John Lawler's comments [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134047/can-conversant-be-a-noun/391433#comment277397_134051).

Answer (score 3):

*[Conversant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conversant)* is an adjective whose primary modern meaning is

> having knowledge or experience —used with *with*

Like most adjectives, it can be used as a noun (i.e. a substantive):

> The AMOLED vs. LCD debate confuses novices but enrages the conversant.

But using it in this way retains the meaning of the adjective. You cannot simply substitute one word for another, shorter word willy-nilly without confusing your audience. *Conversant* is not directly related to *conversation*, and you cannot substitute it for *conversationalist* any more than you can substitute *psychic* and *psychologist* or *seminal* and *insemination*.

Comment: That's the definite generic use of an adjective, meaning 'those people who are conversant', like _the poor, the rich, the educated_. There's another, rather uncommon, sense, however, which is a noun and means 'one party in a conversation', e.g, _Her conversants never failed to remark on her bell-like laughter_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Interesting; I've never encountered that usage before, and did not find it in any of the online dictionaries I consulted.

Comment: OED says: "**B**. _sb._ 1. A person who `converses' or is intimate with another; a familiar acquaintance. _Obs._" The last citation is 1680. So it is definitely Obs. The suffix is still productive, though (_informant, discussant,_ etc.), so it's transparent enough.

Comment: @JohnLawler - at what point do two people conversing become conversants?

Comment: @choster - sorry, unticking based on the comment from JohnLawler.

Comment: @JohnLawler do you want to answer this question so I can tick it? It's had 1k views so an answer would be fitting.

Comment: @choster - given the detail from John Lawler would you care to either fix or delete your answer?