# What would you call "the other party" in a conversation in which you are participating?

Tags: conversation

The ideal word would be "conversee" but that obviously isn't correct. "Recipient" doesn't feel right either. I suppose "interlocutor" is somewhat better, but that doesn't refer to the "other", in this context and feels very formal.

Comment: "My interlocutor" refers to just the other party. I suspect this is for naming a database column, in which case *interlocutor* would indeed be appropriate, because in context it cannot refer to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "conversant" be a noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134047/can-conversant-be-a-noun) Note John Lawler's comment: [*There's another, rather uncommon, sense, however, which is a noun and means '**one party in a conversation**', e.g, Her **conversants** never failed to remark on her bell-like laughter.*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134047/can-conversant-be-a-noun#comment277393_134051)

Comment: @AndrewLeach it is indeed for a database :-) Many thanks

Comment: Well, as long as we're collecting terms, in the trade one refers to people involved in a prototype 2-person conversation as _participants_. They can be viewed also by role, and in a prototype 2-person conversation participants alternate between the roles of _speaker_ and _addressee_. This is the principle of turn-taking, which is fundamental to social organization, among other things.